# Node is showing different version after installation

Tags: node.js

I am installed node version 8.x in my machine.
But if i check node version (node -v) it is showing v13.1.0
May i know what could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you using NVM?

Comment: Nope, i am not using it.

Comment: Try restarting terminal or restarting system and check the path in environment variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Node version manager (nvm)` installed? If not I recommend installing that and it will make switching between node versions a breeze.

`nvm use 8`

There are many guides online on how to set it up.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm